# export path in Dockerfile with '~'

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I try to write Dockerfile from this steps :

```
    # set EOSIO directories
    export EOSIO_LOCATION=~/eosio/eos
    export EOSIO_INSTALL_LOCATION=$EOSIO_LOCATION/../install
    mkdir -p $EOSIO_INSTALL_LOCATION
    # install git
    apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y git
    # clone EOSIO repository
    git clone https://github.com/EOSIO/eos.git $EOSIO_LOCATION
    cd $EOSIO_LOCATION && git submodule update --init --recursive
```

I changed `export EOSIO_LOCATION` to `ENV EOSIO_LOCATION` or `ARG EOSIO_LOCATION` but the path is not correct and the git is not cloned:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
# set EOSIO directories
ENV EOSIO_LOCATION=~/eosio/eos
ENV EOSIO_INSTALL_LOCATION=$EOSIO_LOCATION/../install
RUN mkdir -p $EOSIO_INSTALL_LOCATION && \
        # install git
        apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y git && \
        # clone EOSIO repository
        git clone https://github.com/EOSIO/eos.git $EOSIO_LOCATION && \
        cd $EOSIO_LOCATION && git submodule update --init --recursive
```

How to fix it?

Comment: use $HOME instead ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a Docker image has a fixed filesystem layout, you don't generally need environment variables to point at container directories; and since a Docker image runs a single process as a single user, there isn't really a notion of "home directory".  It's common to use straightforward absolute paths for things.

In this example, I'd just hard-code a path like `/eosio`.

```sh
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# install git
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y git

# clone the repository
# (NOTE: Docker layer caching will _not_ repeat this step if upstream changes)
RUN git clone https://github.com/EOSIO/eos.git /eosio \
 && cd /eosio \
 && git submodule update --init --recursive

# actually build and install it
WORKDIR /eosio
RUN ./scripts/eosio_build.sh \
 && ./scripts/eosio_install.sh
```

(The documentation recommends [using prebuilt binaries](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/install/install-prebuilt-binaries/#ubuntu-1804-package-install) and this will probably be easier and result in a smaller image.)